# pg_archivecleanup

Tags: postgresql, replication, backup

I need to use the pg_archivecleanup command to delete log generated in a primary node from a cluster postgresql but I see that running the next line does not delete anything.

```
 pg_archievecleanup  -d /var/lib/postgresql/000000010000000003400000
```

I have been reviewing and I see that the deletion is done after the backup but I do not know how to do it. I only done a backup full from the database.Can you advise me on how to run it, please?

Comment: Please show us the actual command, free of typos.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is enough to quote [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgarchivecleanup.html):

> `pg_archivecleanup [option...] archivelocation oldestkeptwalfile`
>
> When used as a standalone program all WAL files logically preceding the `oldestkeptwalfile` will be removed from `archivelocation`.